# How to display all fields, including related ones, in a Django Serializer using abbreviated syntax?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, backend

I know I can use this syntax for all fields:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Event
        fields = '__all__'

class GuestList(LogicalDeleteModel):    
    
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event,
                                    through='EventGuestList',
                                    through_fields=('guest_list', 'event'),
                                    related_name='guest_list')
```

But this does NOT include any of the related fields. In this example, I want guest_list to also be a part of the serializer.

I know that I can simply declare all the fields explicitly, including the related ones, but I was wondering if there's any chance I could avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the [depth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) of relationships by adding `depth = 1` in the Class Meta

Comment: Depth does include related objects in the serializer, so your answer is objectively wrong.